# MSVC equivalent to '__builtin_return_address'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, gcc, gnu

With msvc, is there an equivalent to gcc's "__builtin_return_address"?

I'm looking to find the address of the calling function, 1 level deep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[__ReturnAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/returnaddress)

From MSDN:

> The _ReturnAddress intrinsic provides
>   the address of the instruction in the
>   calling function that will be executed
>   after control returns to the caller

Note that on some platforms, the result could be misleading due to tail folding - the compiler might have your inner function return 2 levels deep.  This can commonly occur for code like this:

```
int DoSomething()
{
   return DoSomethingSpecial();
}
```

The compiler could generate code so DoSomethingSpecial returns directly to the caller of DoSomething.

Also, the return address is not trustworthy-enough to make security decisions, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/01/47042.aspx).

Comment: Note that the function is `_ReturnAddress` and not `__ReturnAddress`, as the answer first indicates.